# pySerial in_wating is 1020 all the time on mac Mojave and the reading is full with junk and previous data

Tags: python, pyserial, macos-mojave

pySerial in_wating is 1020 all the time and the reading is full with junk and previous data

Hello,

We have a python software that works great for long time with all the mac osx versions up the now. We try the software on Mac Mojave and it did not work.

we did lot of testing and found that the in_waiting value is zero if the buffer is empty (that is good), but when we send some bytes (no mater if 3 of 3000), the in_waiting value is 1020.

That not all. When we read the 1020 bytes (or 10000), we see lot of junk and data from the previous received values in the reading buffer.

specific about out product, we are using the CP2102. The python software on the mac send parameters to an external sensor, the sensor starts to measure and sends packets of data every 0.1sec. 
with the previous mac version the python check the in_waiting and when it was with the right length we read it and display it. but now we get 1020 all the time and the information is  hidden somewhere in the buffer and there are many results ... HELP :)

thanks

--- Code:

```
def receive(self, i = False, dly = 0.02): 
  sleep(dly) 
  try:
    iw = self.in_waiting
    if 0 == iw:
      log("receive in_waiting=0")
      return 'False'
    if False == i: 
      i = iw 
    if i > iw: 
      log("receive need more then in_waiting="+str(iw))
      return 'False'
    s = self.read(i)
    return s
  except: 
    self.status = 'False' 
  return 'False'
```

Comment: can you show the line where you call `in_waiting`?

Comment: def receive(self, i = False, dly = 0.02):
        sleep(dly)
        try:
            iw = self.in_waiting
            if 0 == iw:
                log("receive in_waiting=0")
                return 'False'
            if False == i:
                i = iw
            if i > iw:
                log("receive need more then in_waiting="+str(iw))
                return 'False'
            s = self.read(i)
            return s
        except:
            self.status = 'False'
            return 'False'